# (WP) Posts Filter Doesn't Work

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on made posts filter function on WP admin. First filter function works, but second not work. I'm suspect it's from `$where .=`, so I'm try to remove first one and just show second filter only. But doesn't work. Are there because incorrect `$wpdb` function?

```
function post_filter($where) {
    if (is_admin()) {
        global $wpdb;
        if (isset($_GET['metakey_first']) && !empty($_GET['metakey_first']) && intval($_GET['metakey_first']) != 0) {
            $metakey_first = intval($_GET['metakey_first']);
            $where. = " AND ID IN (SELECT post_id FROM ".$wpdb - > postmeta." 
    WHERE meta_key='metakey_first' AND meta_value=$metakey_first)";
        }
        if (isset($_GET['metakey_second']) && !empty($_GET['metakey_second']) && intval($_GET['metakey_second']) != 0) {
            $metakey_second = intval($_GET['metakey_second']);
            $where. = " AND ID IN (SELECT post_id FROM ".$wpdb - > postmeta." 
    WHERE meta_key='metakey_second' AND meta_value=$metakey_second)";
        }
    }
    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'post_filter');
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Any error messages? Have you checked the logs? Or are the posts displayed, but not filtered correctly?

Comment: For first one, it works, mean it's show post based on filter value.. For second one, it's not work, it's show all post even not in filter value. Doesn't have any error message.